# Form doesn't appear until long running method completes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# windows forms application that restores a database backup. After `InitializeComponent()` I call a `GetServers()` function that runs a cmd command "sqlcmd -L" and populates a drop down. This takes around 15-20 second to execute.

So when I run the application I have to wait 15-20 seconds before the main form appears. Is there a way to open the form first, and then run the `GetServers()` function?

```
private void GetServers()
{
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c sqlcmd -L");
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
    proc.Start();

    string processOutput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    var lines = processOutput.Split(
    new[] { Environment.NewLine },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        if (!line.Trim().ToUpper().Contains("SERVERS:"))
        cbxServer.Items.Add(line.Trim());
    }

}


public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GetServers();
}
```

Comment: You could make `GetServers` async, that way you wouldn't block your UI thread.

Comment: Will that require to execute GetServers() on a different thread and after return the result back to the UI thread?

Comment: If the form doesn't help before having executed GetServers and you just want to see the form while waiting for GetServers() then move its call to the Shown Event.

Comment: @Germi - If it is made `async` it should then return `string[]` so that the items can be added on the UI thread.

Comment: Another option is to use the Form Shown event handler. This way, your form will load and will be visible while the user waits until the GetServers() is completed. you can have a label explaining the user that the application is initializing and hide it right after the GetServers() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where you could benefit from using a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx).

First, modify your `GetServers` method so that it returns the `lines` collection instead of processing it. Then you can do simething like this (pseudocode and probably not complete, but you get the idea):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (sender, e) => e.Result = GetServers();
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        foreach (var line in (string[])e.Result) {/*Here you add the info to your form*/};

    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: I`ve modified the GetServers() method and now returns an array of strings   (private string[] GetServers() ) but i get an error before the foreach at the "=>" saying that only increment, decrement, await(...) can be used as statement, one at the foreach saying that it is an invalid expression and another one at e.Result in the foreach saying that the name "e" does not exists in the current context.

Comment: This code was intended to just give you an idea of how to do things, it is not a ready to use solution. You should read the documentation for BackgroundWorker in the link provided and craft your own solution.

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it. I couldn't get it to work tho, I've created a new task after the initialization and used Invoke to return the values back. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run your method in `Form`'s `Shown`-event. That would still make the `Form` unresponsive until it's done with the `GetServers()`. The UI is always updated after all code on the UI-thead is executed.

You should check out [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [asyncronous methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried to call it in the form`s Shown event. It works, but it just looks ugly waiting 10 seconds with an almost empty form opened.

Comment: Then you should handle the operations asynchronously. You should check out the links on the answer.